# Is it possible to import smart contracts with different compiler versions?

Tags: compilation, import, hardhat

I'm using hardhat to compile my contracts. I am aware that hardhat is good at compiling contracts with different pragma versions, however, the contracts can't compile because they're importing contracts with different pragma versions. I was thinking of making an import.sol contract as a central source to import other contracts. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, I didn't use hardHat before, but compiling contracts with different versions of solidity introduces compatibility issues between each contract code. an example of such issues is the `abstract` keyword that didn't exist in version `0.4` but does in other versions after that and its usage is mandatory on classes with `virtual` methods.

Your best choice is to modify the contracts to use the latest version of the compiler or a fixed version of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/multiple-solidity-versions) of Hardhat, you can use different solc versions.
You just need to specify for each contract, or use override in the hardhat.config.js file.

About the compatibility issues, Solidity Compiler comes with a tool to "upgrade" your contract. I never used it before, but I think and I hope it helps. Link to [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.2/using-the-compiler.html#solidity-upgrade).

Happy coding! :)